# On Latin reception of Avicenna

Tags: history-of-philosophy, islamic-philosophy, avicenna

I'm looking for an article represents a general picture of Ibn Sina's (Avicenna's) Latin reception in the middle ages.
For example in this book we read about reception of particular aspects:
[https://www.amazon.com/Reception-Avicennas-Metaphysics-Scientia-Graeco-Arabica/dp/B01K0UC6CE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01K0UC6CE)
Or this article is not peculiar to Ibn Sina:
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/arabic-islamic-influence
Do you know an another article?

Comment: SEP has an [Ibn Sina (Avicenna)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ibn-sina/) entry.

Comment: The SEP article linked in the post has a long bibliography list with many items specific to Avicenna's reception, e.g. Aertsen's, Bertolacci's, Black's, Hasse's, and so on. There is also a comprehensive Routledge volume [Ibn Sina and his Influence on the Arabic and Latin World](https://www.routledge.com/Ibn-Sina-and-his-Influence-on-the-Arabic-and-Latin-World-1st-Edition/Janssens/p/book/9780860789871), and a [chapter The reception of Avicenna in Latin medieval culture](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139047890.013) in Cambridge's volume.